# Hyperledger Fabric v1.2 - Failed to invoke chaincode name:"qscc" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have Fabric network setup with 3 VMs which contains 4 organisations each with 2 peers along with respective CouchDB instances,1 dedicated CA and single orderer. I am using Hyperledger Java SDK in order to expose rest API for consumption.

We are facing frequent issues while doing queries be it rich text query or at times with historical queries exception mentioned below. As per the logs I am able to see user Chaincode has successfully retrieved the results of the query but failed while doing a "qscc" Chaincode invocation.

```
2018-08-29 02:43:33.749 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Next -> DEBU 26591 queryResultsItr.Next() returned a record:{"availableDate":"","refTxId":"3b9c439f918a4c4ff558ab803611877d5cd990255f57c5b0b2a1944866982384","userId":"ABC0002","updatedBy":"system"}
2018-08-29 02:43:33.749 UTC [chaincode] HandleGetQueryResult -> DEBU 26592 Got keys and values. Sending RESPONSE
2018-08-29 02:43:33.749 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 26593 [4e6c0cc5] Completed GET_QUERY_RESULT. Sending RESPONSE
2018-08-29 02:43:33.750 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 26594 [4e6c0cc5] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: QUERY_STATE_CLOSE in state ready
2018-08-29 02:43:33.750 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 26595 [4e6c0cc5] handling QUERY_STATE_CLOSE from chaincode
2018-08-29 02:43:33.750 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 26596 [4e6c0cc5] Completed QUERY_STATE_CLOSE. Sending RESPONSE
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 26597 [4e6c0cc5] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [chaincode] Notify -> DEBU 26598 [4e6c0cc5] notifying Txid:4e6c0cc5d95c5686c20d33d6bafa2cf850b1d1615f240c56831c44cf5bb69c79, channelID:mychannel
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 26599 Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 2659a [mychannel][4e6c0cc5d95c5686c20d33d6bafa2cf850b1d1615f240c56831c44cf5bb69c79] Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] GetTxSimulationResults -> DEBU 2659b Simulation completed, getting simulation results
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 2659c Done with transaction simulation / query execution [4e6c0cc5d95c5686c20d33d6bafa2cf850b1d1615f240c56831c44cf5bb69c79]
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 2659d [mychannel][4e6c0cc5] Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 2659e [mychannel][4e6c0cc5] Entry chaincode: name:"mychaincode"
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 2659f [mychannel][4e6c0cc5] escc for chaincode name:"mychaincode"  is escc
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 265a0 Entering endorsement for {plugin: escc, channel: mychannel, tx: 4e6c0cc5d95c5686c20d33d6bafa2cf850b1d1615f240c56831c44cf5bb69c79, chaincode: mychaincode}
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 265a1 Exiting {plugin: escc, channel: mychannel, tx: 4e6c0cc5d95c5686c20d33d6bafa2cf850b1d1615f240c56831c44cf5bb69c79, chaincode: mychaincode}
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 265a2 [mychannel][4e6c0cc5] Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 265a3 Done with transaction simulation / query execution [4e6c0cc5d95c5686c20d33d6bafa2cf850b1d1615f240c56831c44cf5bb69c79]
2018-08-29 02:43:33.751 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 265a4 Exit: request from 10.255.0.4:47828
2018-08-29 02:43:33.977 UTC [gossip/discovery] periodicalSendAlive -> DEBU 265a5 Sleeping 5s
2018-08-29 02:43:34.198 UTC [gossip/discovery] periodicalReconnectToDead -> DEBU 265a6 Sleeping 25s
2018-08-29 02:43:34.711 UTC [gossip/election] waitForInterrupt -> DEBU 265a7 [40 227 139 114 173 5 75 157 49 97 134 49 223 250 188 122 25 48 140 50 245 198 39 79 233 243 124 193 89 118 85 88] : Exiting
2018-08-29 02:43:34.711 UTC [gossip/election] IsLeader -> DEBU 265a8 [40 227 139 114 173 5 75 157 49 97 134 49 223 250 188 122 25 48 140 50 245 198 39 79 233 243 124 193 89 118 85 88] : Returning true
2018-08-29 02:43:34.711 UTC [gossip/election] waitForInterrupt -> DEBU 265a9 [40 227 139 114 173 5 75 157 49 97 134 49 223 250 188 122 25 48 140 50 245 198 39 79 233 243 124 193 89 118 85 88] : Entering
2018-08-29 02:43:35.075 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 265aa Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:35.075 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 265ab [mychannel][8fb2e3710e44df19e8255177885c5ce29a940ea5239b20e7a94791fe2e4faee9] Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:35.077 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 265ac [mychannel][8fb2e371] failed to invoke chaincode name:"qscc" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).Execute
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/handler.go:919
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).execute
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:253
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Invoke
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:239
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:179
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:141
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:136
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
        /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
error sending
failed to execute transaction 8fb2e3710e44df19e8255177885c5ce29a940ea5239b20e7a94791fe2e4faee9
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:181
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:141
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:136
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
        /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
2018-08-29 02:43:35.077 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 265ad [mychannel][8fb2e371] Exit
2018-08-29 02:43:35.077 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 265ae Exit: request from 10.255.0.4:47818
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also come across this issues recently. After checked some related issues and docs, the temporary solutions for me is restart the peer which you found `Failed to invoke chaincode name "qscc"` at its log:

```
docker restart <peer container's id>
```

However, this solution cannot solve the problem completely. But you can check [this issues](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-10540) to get more information( the issues is duplicated by [this](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-11720) and it's still unresolved).

Here is a related comment by Manish Sethi for explaing what happends behind querying ledger:

> Ledger exposes two set of APIs one set of APIs relate to state reads and manipulation and the other set of APIs relate to querying the blockchain status (such as `GetBlockByNumber` and `GetTransactionByID`). The first set of APIs are exposed via transaction simulator and (are meant for a chaincode to use during transaction simulation) and the second set of API are exposed as a direct APIs in the ledger interface (and are meant for clients to know the ledger status).
>
> Keeping the above in mind, a tacit assumption in the ledger design has been that a single gorouting limits it's usage to one of the above set of APIs exclusively. A chaincode limits itself to state related APIs and a ledger status querying client would not need to create a simulator.
>
> However, on the higher layers, since the ledger status related APIs are exposed via chaincode (`qscc`, to be specific), the above assumption is broken. The execution path for answering the ledger status queries obtains a transaction simulator before it reaches the qscc code (which has no use in fact, of the transaction simulator).
>
> More specifically, an additional constraint on these two sets of APIs relates to the fact that two independent external calls to any of the ledger API should give a perceived notion of atomic commit to the block storage and the state. For instance, this should not happen that a client queries the API `GetBlockchainInfo` and finds out that block number 10 is committed but when he submits a subsequent state query, the query returns the state as of block 9 (because, the state update for block 10 are still pending). This is implemented by a pair of locks One lock syncs the state between simulation and statedb commit and another syncs the ledger status related calls with the overall commit. This is done for achieving better performance by halting the simulation to a minimum (only when the updates are actually been dumped to the disk) at the cost of ledger status related queries. Because, the qscc takes a transaction simulator, the above mentioned interaction leads to the reported deadlock. I believe that going forward, one of the suggestions was to expose these ledger status related APIs via grpc interface which will fix this issue. However, I list below three options for completeness...
>
> qscc path not to take hold of a transaction simulator (which is desired otherwise also, as the transaction simulator is an expensive resource as it takes a read lock on the statedb to sync with commit and hence should be taken only for transaction simulations).
>
> An alternate fix could be to implement the above mentioned perceived notion of atomic commit to the block storage and the state by a coarser level single lock but that will impact the throughput an not a desired solution.
>
> Implement the perceived notion of atomic commit yet differently.. which requires some significant work in the interaction between ledger storage and the statedb. In nut shell, exposing the ledger storage a two phase commit. In first step, we append the block and then in the second step, update the BlockchainInfo and blockindexes sunchronized with statedb updates.
> Given, the above, since the first one is anyway desired, my suggestion would be fix that for 1.1 and 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! Though fix for this is told to be provided in Fabric 1.2.1